# Can a Wii U work with a hardware RAID for external HDDs?

Tags: wii-u

I'm looking at a Hardware RAID enclosure [(like this)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816856075&nm_mc=EMC-IGNEFL011714&cm_mmc=EMC-IGNEFL011714-_-EMC-011714-Index-_-ServerRAIDSystems-_-16856075-L024C) for my Wii U. I would like to use external storage so I can fit more games on it, but would like RAID 1 (mirroring) to protect my data since the Wii U's method of "backing up" (manually, game-by-game copying save data in a multi-step process) is far too involved to do on a regular basis.

But I've never used a RAID setup like this before--will it be read just like a single disk and therefore work on a Wii U? Or does this require some drivers normally present on a computer operating system or not? Does it depend on device or are all hardware RAID enclosures usable on a Wii U? I know it will need external power (or 2 USB ports for power) but I'm not sure how the Wii U will treat a hardware RAID'd device.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on RAID implementation for a device. From the specs of [this specific device](http://www.cineraid.com/products/home_h212.htm) it seems that it's hardware configured using DIP switches and doesn't requeres any drivers, specifically

> Supporting OS:
>
> The H212 is OS independent and will work with any OS that supports USB
>   host devices.

That means that it looks like a regular drive to device that is using it. So, unless there is no specific incompatibility the device should work fine with Wii U.